# Can you start off with this game?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

I never played DMC, but can I get this game and not get confused about story line?
Reviews say that this is a rebirth of the series, so can I play this game and feel that I understand what's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DmC is a reboot of the franchise, so while certain elements such as character names are borrowed from the original games, there's no story connection at all. You have nothing to worry about!